# infinite loop, unknown reason

Tags: python, python-3.6, timeit

For some reason this code seems to enter an infinite loop and I have no clue why

```
import timeit

t = timeit.Timer(stmt="for num in num_list: print(num)",
                 setup="num_list = [digit for digit in range(1, 101)]")

print(t.timeit())
```

I have python version 3.6.2 installed via Anaconda.

I've tried running it in the Spyder IDE and in command prompt, both have the same results.

If I change the setup to be generator instead of list comprehension everything works fine, the same can be said about running identical code out of timeit.

I've even tried restarting my computer because ya know, I have to try turning it off and on again, it works for most things.

Comment: Have you tried it without timeit?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html - default interations is 1,000,000.

Comment: @SuperStew I confirmed it works outside of timeit already in my original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not an infinite loop – just a long one. `setup` only runs once, so when you use a generator expression, it gets consumed after the first run of `stmt` and nothing further is printed. When you use a list comprehension, each list element is printed every run of `stmt`, resulting in 100 × 1000000 calls to `print`. (1 million is the default number of iterations for `Timer.timeit()`.)